# Git Branch looks something strange?

Tags: git, merge, branch

my branch looks like this

Username((8dad1cf...)*)project name

Don't know how to get out of it.
was trying some commands for committing,
think applied one with merge , and delete commands on it.
could anyone please help and aid

before it gets there it was (|REBASE-m)

git status replays

```
 $git status
HEAD detached from 3592c28
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>...`enter code here`" to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
       modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you paste whatever command you are running to see it and its output? (in text, please, no pics). Add that information to the question by editing it.

Comment: I'm sure it's a customized `$PS1` prompt from `bash` or `zsh` that uses `__git_ps1`. `Username` is your name;`((8dad1cf...)*)` is a 7-chars prefix of the SHA1 hash of the current (`HEAD`) commit + indication that you have some uncommitted changes; `project name` is the current directory. The SHA1 suggests that you're in [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+what+is+detached+HEAD) state. Perhaps you want to do `git checkout master`

Comment: And, besides what @phd already said, the `|REBASE-m` that you had indicated that you were in the middle of a conflicted rebase. Use `git status` to see if you are still in the middle of that conflicted rebase.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! are you using Mac or windows ?

Comment: @phd Ok it worked for me ! thanks “git checkout master “

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're on `HEAD detached` mode.
Long story short: you're on not latest commit on current branch, so you can assume that it's "read-only" mode.

Use:

```
git checkout xxx
```

where xxx is the branch name / latest commit hash.

Answer (score 0):

Applyed "git checkout master"
the result

```
$git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
M       README.md
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 2 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Username (master *) project name
```